# What will remove this screen printed logo without destroying the polycarbonate safety sunglasses lens?

Tags: solvents, plastics, cleaning

I bought some safety sunglasses and didn't notice until I'd taken the tags off that there's an annoying logo painted or printed right in my field of view.  (You can feel with your fingertips or fingernails that it is actually on the surface and not, for instance, laser etched into the surface.)  What household or garage chemicals would take it off without destroying the polycarbonate lens?

I recently did some PVC pipe work and I'm confident the purple primer would take this right off.  I'm not confident it wouldn't also dissolve the polycarbonate.  PVC... polycarbonate... is the latter likely to be resistant to something that dissolves the former?

Otherwise what else should I try?  I also have a can of stuff for cleaning paint brushes.

[image]

Comment: You might experiment in a very small spot with a cotton applicator and milder solvent, e.g. 91% or stronger ethyl or isopropyl alcohol, then try stronger solvents such as naphtha and then diethyl ether, if the previous doesn't work. **N.B.** These are either flammable or *highly* flammable -- use caution.

Comment: Test also on other PC objects like old CD/DVD before the glasses.